# Check number of decimal places in numeric string

Tags: c#

Here is a string.

```
String num = "10.65"
```

If the user enters `10.653` then it should tell the user that this takes only up to two decimal places. How can I check this?

Comment: you can check length of string after point that it is of length 2 or not.

Comment: use any mask editors which will help to enter specific format example http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Comment: You can use regular expressions to validate input as well.

Comment: @raymond You should read http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check, if the parsed value rounded up to 2 decimal places changes:

```
var input = "10.625";

double value;
if(!double.TryParse(input, out value) || Math.Round(value, 2) != value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code snippet. it works good but when string comes in 132898.781 format then Math.Round change the string into 132898.78 so at this point the above code gets failed.

Comment: @user3064724 this was as per your requirement: "`if user enter 10.653 then it should tell user that this takes only amount up to two decimal places.`"

Comment: @user3064724 That's exactly what you've asked. `13289.7899` has more then 2 decimal places, and that's why my code prints *'Wrong input'*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned "user enters", I guess this is a field on screen. If yes, why not use a numeric input control? Is this web or windows form?